# Pandas read_sql from MS SQL gets stuck for queries with 275+ chars in linux

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, linux, sqlalchemy

I have a strange problem while executing `pandas.read_sql()` in linux for MS SQL servers.
Whenever the query string gets over 274 characters, it gets stuck indefinitely, even though it has already fetched the data (if I `ctrl` + `D` out of the python shell, it displays the data before crashing the python shell).

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_sql('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ************.*****.*****************                                                                                                                                                                                         
                               ', '<constring>')
```

This query works alright (274 chars), but if I were to add just a single space to it, it'll get stuck in this line forever.
(The stars are my schema, table, and field names, and the constring is my connection string).

By the way, this happens only while connecting to SQL Server databases (I've tested MySQL and it was fine), and only in Linux machines (ubuntu); it is fine on Windows, too.

I'm using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server by the way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. If I take the above I actually initially get an error, as you have a line break but don't wrap your literal string in triple single quotes (`'''`). If I fix that, the query runs fine (at both more than, and less than 275 characters).

Comment: I guess the line break had been added in the question editor. As I said, it only happens when my query string passes over a certain character limit. I've tested with triple quotes, but this still keeps happening.

Comment: The current query I have in the editor is 296 characters, including the line break and carriage return. If I remove that (taking it to 294) it still works. Perhaps we need more here to create an actual [mre].

Comment: I understand that this is hard to replicate... I've queried the same way on linux before and haven't had this happen to me (except in one occasion, while I was querying in a similar scenario on a Zeppelin notebook server. Back then I couldn't solve the problem either, ended up thinking something was wrong with the Zeppelin server). Anyway, cheers and thank you for your response.

Comment: Try using `read_sql_query()` instead of `read_sql()`

Comment: @GordThompson You're my savior!!!

Comment: sorry but that does not work either,.