# pd.read_sql and pd.read_sql_query hang upon execution, how to troubleshoot this?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to write a pandas dataframe to a table in MySQL database on my laptop, so this is local.  The dataframe is filled with some 2M rows from a read_sql query with engine connection parameter stream_results=True, see my code below.

Problem is that when I call pd.to_sql() and try to write that chunk of a dataframe to the local database table, the execution just hangs.  Why does it take so long?  How would I go about troubleshooting this or speeding it up?

I have no idea what is going on or how to troubleshoot this?  Any suggestions?  Here is my code:

` try:
# Connect to local database
database_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root:1234@localhost:3306'
localEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_uri)

```
    with localEngine.connect().execution_options(
        stream_results=True) as conn_local:

        result = conn_local.execute(text("USE ConsumerExpenditures10;"))

        result = conn_local.execute(text("""
                                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOADING_TABLE (
                                        EXPENDITURE_ID varchar(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                                        HOUSEHOLD_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                                        YEAR YEAR NOT NULL,
                                        MONTH INT(11) NOT NULL, 
                                        PRODUCT_CODE VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL,
                                        COST DOUBLE NOT NULL,
                                        GIFT INT NOT NULL,
                                        IS_TRAINING INT(255) NOT NULL,
                                        MARITAL VARCHAR(25),
                                        SEX VARCHAR(25),
                                        AGE INT,
                                        WORK_STATUS VARCHAR(25),
                                        INCOME_RANK double,
                                        INCOME_RANK_1 double,
                                        INCOME_RANK_2 double,
                                        INCOME_RANK_3 double,
                                        INCOME_RANK_4 double,
                                        INCOME_RANK_5 double,
                                        INCOME_RANK_MEAN double,
                                        FEDERAL_FUNDS_TARGET_RATE double, 
                                        FEDERAL_FUNDS_UPPER_TARGET double,
                                        FEDERAL_FUNDS_LOWER_TARGET double,
                                        EFFECTIVE_FEDERAL_FUNDS_RATE double,
                                        REAL_GDP double,
                                        UNEMPLOYMENT_RATE double, 
                                        INFLATION_RATE double,
                                        CPI double)
                                    """))

        # TRANSFORMATION #9 - Create comprehensive table of GDP, CPI and Consumer Expenditures Data
        # with each row being one Consumer Expenditure Purchase
        query = text("""select e.expenditure_id, e.household_id, e.year, e.month, e.product_code, 
                        e.cost, e.gift, e.is_training, 
                        hm.marital, hm.sex, hm.age, hm.work_status, h.income_rank, 
                        h.income_rank_1, h.income_rank_2, h.income_rank_3, h.income_rank_4, 
                        h.income_rank_5, h.income_rank_mean, g.FEDERAL_FUNDS_TARGET_RATE, 
                        g.FEDERAL_FUNDS_UPPER_TARGET, g.FEDERAL_FUNDS_LOWER_TARGET, 
                        g.EFFECTIVE_FEDERAL_FUNDS_RATE, 
                        g.REAL_GDP, g.UNEMPLOYMENT_RATE, g.INFLATION_RATE, c.CPI
                        from expenditures e
                        inner join household_members hm 
                        on hm.household_id = e.HOUSEHOLD_ID 
                        inner join households h
                        on h.household_id = hm.HOUSEHOLD_ID
                        inner join gdp g 
                        on g.gdp_year = e.`YEAR`
                        inner join cpi c 
                        on c.CPI_YEAR = g.gdp_year""")

        # https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-sql-chunking/
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711599/pandas-read-sql-from-ms-sql-gets-stuck-for-queries-with-275-chars-in-linux
        # Takes too long to execute this query: df_final_table = pd.read_sql(query, conn_local)
        # So we have to do it in chunks to load into a pandas dataframe and then write that to the loading_table
        for chunk_dataframe in pd.read_sql_query(query, conn_local, chunksize=10):
            print(
                f"Got dataframe w/{len(chunk_dataframe)} rows"
            )

            # write this dataframe chunk into the LOADING_TABLE
            result = chunk_dataframe.to_sql(name='LOADING_TABLE', con=conn_local, if_exists='append', index=False)>>>>>> execution hangs right here in PyCharm debugger!

     
        conn_local.commit()`
```

Do you have any suggestions on what I can do trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Are these queries running as part of a greater execution process? Maybe you are getting a deadlock somewhere. Also due to an error happening initially, maybe Python exited before closing its connections fully and now your connections to the DB are full. If all of this fails, try running these queries in mysql manually and compare results

Comment: I am not sure.  This is all part of an ETL pipeline, so I also opened some other connections to the local database earlier but they should be closed?  But this is helpful, let me check the connections in workbench....

Comment: Just checked with this on the command line: show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';....it says 6....is that too many?

Comment: Well I am not sure what your config is like but 6 doesn't sound like a lot for an ETL pipeline. But I am not sure that's the right matric. IIRC it's something like `mysql> show full processlist;`. Also still run the queries manually and see if you run into the same problem

Comment: I did some more sleuthing and it seems I can use the chunksize parameter and "multi" in to_sql() to speed things up.  Also thanks for the tip, I'll try it out.  Are you familiar with ETL pipelines?  I'm a student and would like to learn more, do you have any suggestions on books I could read or online websites I should frequent?